# Can oracles be used to implement inter blockchain communication?

Tags: sidechain, ibc, cross-chain

Do we need to wait for the version of eos which will support ibc for side chains or can we implement a poor man's version with external api which will listen for events on the main eos and another chain and pass messages between them?

Will having several copies of the oracle api service minimize the centralization risk?

Am I having a huge blind spot somewhere?